# jsonb_set code is executing but json_set code is not executing with postgresql table and error is

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
qry = """ UPDATE test_jsonb SET details = jsonb_set(details,'{address, flat}', '201'::jsonb) WHERE id = 1 """
cursor.execute(qry)
conn.commit()
print 'Json Element Updated Successfully'
```

Json Element Updated Successfully

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
qry = """ UPDATE test_json SET details = json_set(details,'{address, flat}', '201'::json) WHERE id = 1  """
cursor.execute(qry)
conn.commit()
print 'Json Element Updated Successfully'
```

ProgrammingError: function json_set(json, unknown, json) does not exist
LINE 1:  UPDATE test_json SET details = json_set(details,'{address, ...
                                        ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type cas

Comment: There simply is no `json_set()` function: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html You can only do that with `jsonb`

Comment: thanks! how can i update a json field?

Comment: You can cast it to `jsonb`, use `jsonb_set` and cast the result back.

Comment: thanks! That worked!